# Why does my for loop adds an object simultaneously?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have this application which has an array element of 4. I'm required to add each single Room object into the array when input by the user and he/she can input up to 4 objects. But when i only input one Room object, it shows tat all the elements in the array got added by the object. May i know why and can someone please help?
Thanks!

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class TestRoom {

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    String[] roomsInHouse = new String[4];
    int answer;

    do{
    String nameOfRoom = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the name of the room");
    String dimsOfRoom = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the dimension of the room in feet L X W X H");

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(dimsOfRoom);
    double l = userInput.nextDouble();
    double w = userInput.nextDouble();
    double h = userInput.nextDouble();

    Room roomDetails = new Room(nameOfRoom, l, w, h);

    String n = Double.toString(l);
    String o = Double.toString(w);
    String p = Double.toString(h);

    for(int i = 0; i < roomsInHouse.length; i++)
    {
        roomsInHouse[i] = nameOfRoom + dimsOfRoom;
    }   

    answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Input another room?", "Area/Volume calculator", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);

    } while(answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

    for(String j: roomsInHouse)
    {
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}

}
```

Ok I have just changed my coding and thanks to you guys' contributions, I understand what went wrong. Cheers!

```
int counter = 0;

roomsInHouse[counter++] = nameOfRoom + dimsOfRoom;  

answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Input another room?", "Area/Volume calculator", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);

} while(answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION && counter < 4);
```

Comment: "But when i only input one Room object, it shows tat all the elements in the array got added by the object." Isn't it precisely what the nested `for` loop is doing???

Comment: are you sure you are entering the name of the room? because I don't see it in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right here you are filling up the whole array with a single room. `roomsInHouse.length` will always return 4

```
for(int i = 0; i < roomsInHouse.length; i++)
{
    roomsInHouse[i] = nameOfRoom + dimsOfRoom;
}
```

You can change your code accordingly

```
String[] roomsInHouse = new String[4];
int n = 0;
int answer;
```

and then later:

```
roomsInHouse[n++] = nameOfRoom + dimsOfRoom;
```

After that just check if `n < 4`, which means that more rooms can be added.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you question right, you are saying that your array gets full when the user inputs just 1 room. If that's the case I think that.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < roomsInHouse.length; i++)
    {
    roomsInHouse[i] = nameOfRoom + dimsOfRoom;
    }
```

Is your problem, because it is looping through all the array.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is in your for loop with in the do-while loop......

As u are iterating **"roomsInHouse.lenght"** times for every interation of do-while loop.....the array gets rewritten for every interation....

Do the following correction to your code....

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class TestRoom {

public static void main(String [] args)
{
String[] roomsInHouse = new String[4];
int answer;
int counter=0;
do{
String nameOfRoom = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the name of the room");
String dimsOfRoom = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the dimension of the room in feet L X W X H");

Scanner userInput = new Scanner(dimsOfRoom);
double l = userInput.nextDouble();
double w = userInput.nextDouble();
double h = userInput.nextDouble();

Room roomDetails = new Room(nameOfRoom, l, w, h);

String n = Double.toString(l);
String o = Double.toString(w);
String p = Double.toString(h);


roomsInHouse[counter] = nameOfRoom + dimsOfRoom;

counter++;
answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Input another room?", "Area/Volume calculator", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);

} while(answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

for(String j: roomsInHouse)
{
    System.out.println(j);
}
```

}

}

Comment: What happens after the fourth iteration?

Comment: I'm asking what if the user keep entering yes to enter more rooms even after the array is full? You should add another condition to the while statement

Comment: @Jaitheradevi hi there, erm it doesn't work only the first element of the array got populated  even though if i entered 3 rooms.